# mouseout when leaving a parent . . . only if the child meets a selector

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, mouseout on a parent div fires when the mouse leaves that parent and enters a child div, and a mouseover on the parent fires when the mouse leaves the child and re-enters the parent. That's what I want . . . but only if the child has a certain attribute, say [imporant="very"]. Otherwise, I want the traversal of the child to be ignored.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
$('.parent').on('mouseover', '.child[important="very"]', function(e){

}).on('mouseout', '.child[important="very"]', function(e){

})
```

Note that these are triggered on the child. You can still access the parent, of course. But `$(e.target)` will be your child, not the parent.

Another approach is to use `.has()`:

```js
$('.parent').has(".child[important=\"very\"]")
  .on('mouseover', function(e){

   })
  .on('mouseout', function(e){

  })
```

In this example, `$('e.target')` will return the jQuery wrapper around `.parent`.

Comment: .on instead of .bind. Right. Thanks!